# Generating smaller previews of selected images from image picker controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerviewcontroller

Here is what I am planning:

- user taps on a button.
- a uiimage picker view controller displays
- user selects an image
- a thumbnail view of selected image should be saved in my application.
  ( like ui picker view has after selecting albums, there is thumbnail view )

Up to three points I can do. But I don't know about creating thumbnail view of selected image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Undocumented `UIImage` resizing](http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2008/10/30/undocumented-uiimage-resizing/).

Answer (score 3):

Make a small bitmap the size of your thumbnail.  Draw your picture into it.  Take the bitmap and turn it into a UIImage and save it.

Here is an implementation:

[iPhone - Multiple CGBitmapContextCreateImage Calls - ObjectAlloc climbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436465/)

Answer (score 2):

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

This is a fantastic read for image manipulation.